# How to make Radial Skills Bars

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know where I could find a nice tutorial/guide/info on making radial skills bars like the one shown [in this website?](http://www.sonofpat.com/)

Comment: why don't you press F12 and check its CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation of the source on the page I found it's made with [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes look at the [polar clock](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html) it's really simple. It's not a tutorial though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ as a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

[Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) (a fantastic vector image library) is used for that effect.

If you want a more simple and easy to implement (but not as flashy) solution, you can also check out [jQuery Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/).

Since you are asking for tutorials or how-tos, you should probably go with the latter if possible, since Raphael is a bit more advanced (and much more powerful).  However Raphael does have some tutorials available if you google around a bit.